# How to Parse JSON response from Sabre API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hello anyone knows how to JQuery Parse this type of JSON response. This response is coming from Sabre API.

```js
object(SharedContext) #3 (1) {
  ["results":"SharedContext":private]= >
  array(7) {
    ["SECURITY"] =>
    NULL
      ["origin"] =>
      string(3)
    "LAX" ["destination"] =>
    string(3)
    "JFK" ["departureDate"] =>
    string(10)
    "2018-08-30" ["LeadPriceCalendar"] =>
    object(stdClass) #6 (4) {
      ["OriginLocation"]= >
      string(3)
    "LAX" ["DestinationLocation"] =>
    string(3)
    "JFK" ["FareInfo"] =>
    array(1) {
        [0] =>
        object(stdClass) #8 (6) {
          ["LowestFare"]= >
          object(stdClass) #9 (2) {
            ["AirlineCodes"]= >
          array(1) {
            [0] =>
            string(2)
            "AS"
          }
          ["Fare"] =>
          float(296.4)
      }
```

Full JSON response here: [json response link](https://pastebin.com/qSAUJsQU)

**Any help is very much appreciated**

Comment: it isn't JSON, it look more like php array, object

Comment: Hi Sir, Yes its a php array object format. But then the response will then be json_encoded(). The question is how to access those array elements after the passing the json response to frontend

Comment: If you use json_encoded(), then in frontend javascript use `JSON.parse(data)` - data is the response after you use json_encoded().

Comment: Exactly sir. You can parse on the frontend. my question is on how to access those array elements. 
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(data)

I cant seem to access the array elements using the variable. Given that the array objects is on multi-dimension